# displaying a post thumbnail depending on category in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to display a specific post thumbnail image based on the category ID, something like this:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {

      if ( cat = 2 ) {
      echo '<img src="image1.jpg" width="" height="" class="live-holder-img" />';
      } elseif( cat = 3 ) {
      echo '<img src="image2.jpg" width="" height="" class="live-holder-img" />';
      } else {
      echo '<img src="default.jpg" width="" height="" class="default" />'
      }

 ?>
```

Comment: Is this code within [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look into category templates: http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

The quick solution would be something like this:

```
if (is_category('1')) {
    echo '<img src="image1.jpg" width="" height="" class="live-holder-img" />';
} else if (is_category('2')) {
    echo '<img src="image2.jpg" width="" height="" class="live-holder-img" />';
} else {
    echo '<img src="default.jpg" width="" height="" class="default" />';
}

//you can also do this by name
if (is_category('Category A')) {
    echo '<img src="image1.jpg" width="" height="" class="live-holder-img" />';
} else if (is_category('Category B')) {
    echo '<img src="image2.jpg" width="" height="" class="live-holder-img" />';
} else {
    echo '<img src="default.jpg" width="" height="" class="default" />';
}
```

is_category function reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category